# How to load vector registers from integer registers in Arm64? (M1)

Tags: assembly, arm64, neon

This is a question about SIMD instructions on AArch64 on an M1.

I am working on a routine that works entirely inside the registers. All the memory reads and writes occur outside of the main loop. The first routine loads pseudo-random bits into registers x14-x22 (excluding x18).

Other than writing those values to memory, I cannot seem to figure out how to load that series of bits to the v5-v8 vector registers without writing them to memory first. I do not want to do that. Asking me why won't be particularly helpful.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I cannot find it in any of my resources.

```
                fmov    d5, x14
                rev64 v5.2d, v5.2d. <--- error!
                ror   q5, q5, #8 <----error!
                fmov   d6, x16
                
                fmov   d6, x17
                fmov   d7, x19
                fmov   d7, x20
                fmov   d8, x21
                fmov   d8, x22
```

In the above code, I'm able to load the lower 64 bits with what I want, but I cannot seem to figure out how to rotate the bits over.

In 32-bit arm you can stack these directly.

Comment: If you want pseudo-random bits in vector registers, xorshift128+ vectorizes very nicely with just 64-bit element-wise shift, XOR, and integer addition so you could just generate random bits in SIMD regs in the first place.  (With two independent seeds).  See [AVX/SSE version of xorshift128+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24001930) for an AVX2 version for example.  If you need a higher quality PRNG than that, you could investigate other options, like possibly `xorshift*` (requires a multiply) or different algorithms entirely.

Comment: Re: your original problem: https://godbolt.org/z/8s3e3P7c9 shows how gcc and clang do it with `fmov` and `mov     v0.d[1], x1`, or GCC using `fmov` and then `ins` twice (not sure why)

Comment: I'm sure it does and that is the algorithm I'm using, but I have no more vector register space. Thanks for showing me a way to do it in your link.

Comment: You're already using all 32 vector regs??  And you can't spill/reload the PRNG or anything else?  If you can hide the store/reload latency, or just reload a constant or loop invariant at some point, that's likely better than running scalar xorshift+ and spending even more instructions getting the results into vectors.  (Unless front-end bandwidth is much wider than vector ALU throughput in the back-end, if vector ALU execution units are the bottleneck.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: `mov` and `ins` are the same instruction here, just assembler aliases.  The duplicated `ins` doesn't make any sense and seems like a compiler bug.

Comment: Reported it: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104039

Comment: Thank you all so much! I got it working. I think I was just making typos. I wish the manuals had just one line of example code! Again, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4):

Already answered in comments by Peter Cordes, just promoting to an answer:

You want the [`ins`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/k/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/INS--vector--general-) instruction.  It moves a general-purpose register into a specified element of a vector register, leaving other element unchanged.

```
fmov d6, x16     // move x16 into d6, which is the low half of v6; high half is zeroed
ins v6.d[1], x17 // insert x17 into high half of v6; leave low half unchanged
```

You can also write `mov v6.d[1], x17` which is an assembler alias for the same thing.  (The instruction will disassemble as `mov`.)

You might think that it would be more natural to write

```
ins v6.d[0], x16
ins v6.d[1], x17
```

but then you would have a false input dependency on the previous value of `v6`.  The `fmov`, since it zeroes the rest of the vector register, ensures that the previous value of `v6` is irrelevant, and out-of-order execution need not wait for it to be ready.

For future reference, instructions for moving elements to / from / between / within vector registers are listed in the Armv8 Architecture Reference Manual section C3.5.13 (in my version), "SIMD move".

Comment: Thank you so much to you and Peter! I got it working!